Failing to start Akka.NET cluster with Azure discovery
I'm trying to a localhost demo cluster. Just running the same console process multiple times localhost, using different ports for each node. I tried using Azure discovery to get the nodes to find each other. The nodes are creating the lookup table in Azure Table, but they are not creating any entries in the table and do not succeed in discovering each other.
Here's the startup code:
const string hostName = "localhost";
const string actorSystemName = "demo";
const string serviceName = "Counting";
const string counterRole = "CountersRole";
const int numberOfShards = 20;

builder.Services.AddAkka(actorSystemName, (akka, serviceProvider) =>
{
    akka.WithRemoting(hostName, remotingPort)
        .WithAkkaManagement(mgmt =>
        {
            mgmt.HostName = hostName;
            mgmt.Port = managementPort;
        })
        .WithClustering(new ClusterOptions
        {
            Roles = [counterRole]
        })
        .WithClusterBootstrap(bootstrap =>
        {
            bootstrap.ContactPointDiscovery.ServiceName = serviceName;
        })
        .WithAzureDiscovery(discovery =>
        {
            discovery.ConnectionString = GetConnectionString(ConnectionStringKey.AzureTable);
            discovery.TableName = "AkkaDiscovery";

            discovery.HostName = hostName;
            discovery.Port = managementPort;
            
            discovery.ServiceName = serviceName;
        })
        .WithShardRegion<ICounters>("counters",
            ICounters.CounterProps,
            new CounterMessageExtractor(numberOfShards),
            new ShardOptions { Role = counterRole });
});


All connectivity seems to be fine, the "AkkaDiscovery" table gets created in Azure Table, but the lookup mechanism doesn't find the other nodes. When I use Azurite, I notice that the only API call to Azurity is the one to create the table. Not a single other write or query to the Azure Table is being performed.
Here's the console output. Looks like Akka.NET doesn't even try to lookup possible nodes (based on the "filtered to an empty array"). Any explanation? I'm probably missing something very essential in the startup code...

Thanks for any help!
